# Rxjava not working in signed apk

Tags: android, proguard, rx-java

I am using `rxjava` in my app, it works fine when I test in, but when I try to run the signed `apk` file in my android devices, the app crashed when it comes to the code of `rxjava`, I have added this in `proguard-rules`,but the app still crashed , anyone has idea of the reason?

Comment: Where is your log, stacktrace?

Comment: code and error please otherwise we can't help you

Comment: actually this problem only occurs when I install the signed apk file into my phone, so I can't actually debug the problem, is there anyway I can get the log when it is installed on the phone, cause it works fine when I test it using computers

Comment: @SiyuanHu then add ACRA or Crashlytics to the app to get the stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

Please show the progaurd rules you have added. Make sure you have added all of the rules below

```
     -keep class rx.schedulers.Schedulers {
         public static <methods>;
        }
     -keep class rx.schedulers.ImmediateScheduler {
         public <methods>;
        }
     -keep class rx.schedulers.TestScheduler {
        public <methods>;
     }
     -keep class rx.schedulers.Schedulers {
        public static ** test();
       }
      -keepclassmembers class rx.internal.util.unsafe.*ArrayQueue*Field* {
       long producerIndex;
       long consumerIndex;
      }
     -keepclassmembers class rx.internal.util.unsafe.BaseLinkedQueueProducerNodeRef {
        long producerNode;
         long consumerNode;
      }
```

Comment: I have exactly added this, but still not working, is there anything need to do apart from add proguard rules?

Comment: Post your log when it crashes. It will be helpful